# Trying to store the return of a char * function into a char array

Tags: c

```
char* getStationName(int stationID) {

    if (stationID < 0 || stationID >= MAX_STATIONS || !AllStationNames[stationID]) 
        return "Unknown";

    return AllStationNames[stationID];
}
```

AllStationNames function is here: (http://pastebin.com/zmmrUXTM) It is an array of strings:

```
char *AllStationNames[MAX_STATIONS] = {
[1] = "Ian Stewart Complex/Mt. Douglas High School",
[3] = "Strawberry Vale Elementary School",
...
[197] = "RASC Victoria Centre",
[199] = "Trial Island Lightstation",
[200] = "Longacre",
};
```

I'm trying to input that integer, and retrieve the string using this function, then store it into a struct, kinda looks like this.

```
MapMarker mapInfo[t];
int k;
for(k=0; k < MAX_STATIONS; k++) {

    char* returned_str = getStationName( stationInfo[k].stationID );
    mapInfo[k].markerName = returned_str;
}
```

This gives me a pointer without cast error. Really have no idea what to do from here.

Comment: What is the definition of `MapMarker` and of `markerName`?

Comment: MapMarker is a struct with a location.latitude and location.longitude (Both floats) and markerName is a char markerName[100] char array (string). The first is kinda irrelevant, I'll remove it as it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, the definition of `MapMarker` is such:

```
struct MapMarker {
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
    char markerName[100];
};
```

In this case, `markerName` exists as a *value* member of `MapMarker`, `markeName` is not a pointer to a string, but a string itself (with a fixed length of 100 elements).

If you're using C, then you'll have to use strcpy, and also make sure you're disposing of `MapMarker` instances correctly if you're allocating them on the heap:

```
char* stationName = getStationName( stationInfo[k].stationID );
strcpy( &mapInfo[k].markerName, stationName );
```

I'll suffix my answer with a dire-warning to avoid C-style string processing functions because they're unsafe w.r.t.: buffer-overflows (e.g. what if `stationName` is longer than 100 bytes? and don't forget about null terminators).

Comment: I've changed my function as follows: http://pastebin.com/YJJm6W30. But I get the error "passing argument 1 of strcpy from incompatible pointer type".

Answer (score 0):

there are many solutions to this problem.

if you know the max length of the station name, your struct could have

```
struct MapMarker {
...

char markerName[MAX_STATION_NAME_LENGTH];
} ;
```

and then you can strcpy (mapInfo[k].markerName, returned_str);

---

if you don't now the max length then you could strdup it:

mapInfo[k].markerName = strdup(returned_str);
(markerName would need to be a char *)

but then you need to free it properly.

---

if you have the option of c++ you could use a std::string

```
struct MapMarker {
...
std::string markerName;
} ;
```

in which case your code would work correctly.

---

if you know all of your station names will be the same through the execution of your program, you actually don't need to copy it.

except you should probably use

const char *, instead of char *

(markerName would be const char *)

---

in my experience with strdup, it has some wackiness with memory allocation on some systems...  so you might want to do something like:

```
char *myStrdup (char *s)
{
   char *r = malloc(strlen(s)+1);
   strcpy(r, s);
   return r;
}
```

---

hope this helps

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UeQWQWM7. I've written it like so, but my program crashes when I try to printf("%s", mapInfo[k].markerName);. Any ideas?